# SQL: count all tasks that belong to a user inside each project

Tags: sql

I need to get the number of tasks that belong to a user inside each project on the system. The tables are:

Projects:
ID, Name

Tasks:
ID, ProjectID, Assignee(the user)

Right now I'm doing this query:

```
SELECT Projects.ID, Projects.Name, COUNT(*) 
FROM Tasks JOIN Projects ON Tasks.ProjectID = Projects.ID 
WHERE Assignee=1 GROUP BY Projects.ID;
```

Which only works partially. IT returns the number of tasks but only for the projects which have tasks assigned to the user. I'd like the query to return all projects in the system, even if no task has been assigned.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

`LEFT JOIN` operates different from `INNER JOIN`. What it does is it returns all records from the *lefthand side table* which is `Projects` whether it has a match or none on the *righthand side* table which is `Tasks`.

```
SELECT  Projects.ID, Projects.Name, COUNT(Tasks.ProjectID) 
FROM    Projects  
        LEFT JOIN Tasks 
            ON Tasks.ProjectID = Projects.ID AND
                Assignee=1
GROUP   BY Projects.ID;
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Greetings, this query does not work. It returns 1 for projects which have no tasks at all.

Comment: oops sorry, it should be `COUNT(Tasks.ProjectID)`. please try again.

Comment: I tried to make this work for issues too by adding another left join clause but it didn't work:

SELECT Projects.ID, Projects.Name, COUNT(Tasks.ProjectID), COUNT(Issues.ProjectID) FROM Projects 
LEFT JOIN Tasks ON Tasks.ProjectID = Projects.ID AND Tasks.Assignee=1
LEFT JOIN Issues ON Issues.ProjectID = Projects.ID AND Issues.Assignee=1
GROUP BY Projects.ID;

Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: you need to calculate each on a separate subquery because it causes to shortcircuit some records.

Comment: oops, try this first `COUNT(DISTINCT Tasks.ID), 
  COUNT(DISTINCT Issues.ID)` let me know if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you need all the projects you need `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` instead of `JOIN`:

```
SELECT Projects.ID, Projects.Name, COUNT(Projects.ID) 
FROM Tasks RIGHT OUTER JOIN Projects 
ON Tasks.ProjectID = Projects.ID 
AND Assignee=1 GROUP BY Projects.ID;
```

Comment: Greetings, this query does not work. It returns 1 for projects which have no tasks at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Projects.ID, Projects.Name, COUNT(*) 
FROM Projects JOIN Tasks ON Tasks.ProjectID = Projects.ID 
WHERE Assignee=1 GROUP BY Projects.ID;
```